# php array in another function

Tags: php, arrays, function

Ok now its weird but when i print the array in the test1 function its prints all the arrays but when it display it from the test2 function its displays only the last records can anyone tell me where i am wrong?

```
class template{
    private $block = array();
    private $page;

    public function test1($data){
        foreach($data as $k => $v){
            $this->block[$k] = $v;
        }
        print_r ($this->block);
    }

    public function test2(){
        print_r ($this->block);
    }
}

$template = new template();

while($row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($bbcat)){
    $template->test1(array("TIT" => $row1['title']));
    while($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($bbscat)){
        $template->test1(array("FTIT" => $row2['title']));

    }
}
```

Comment: you don't need to create your own template. There are tons already done

Comment: You're not calling `test2()` anywhere...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because the foreach loop is looping and setting `$this->block`. So once it's done the last iteration `$this->block` is now set to the data in the last loop.

**CLARIFICATION**

Every loop we do in the foreach loop is setting `$this->block` to some new data. Once the last iteration of the loop has finished we are given the data which was outputted in the final loop.

Does that make more sense?

Comment: `+1` but the wording might need to be fixed bc it took me a little to get it

Comment: So is there anyway to improve it?

Answer (score 0):

The reason you only see the last record is because you overwrite all previous records, as you do this in your `while`-loop:

```
$template->test1(array("TIT" => $row1['title']));
```

Then inside `test1()` you do a rather weird statement:

```
public function test1($data){
    foreach($data as $k => $v){
        $this->block[$k] = $v;
    }
    print_r ($this->block);
}
```

You do `foreach($data as $k => $v)`, which is not neccesary, since there is only ONE value in the array (one key value pair). Nonetheless, you assing `$this->block[$k] = $v;` and `$k` is the same **everytime** (`TIT` and `FTIT`), so you overwrite all previous set values each time you call `test1()`.

If you then call `test2()`, which has no 'set' capabilities, but rather only displays `$this->block`, you only get the last value for `TIT` and `FTIT`.